# Как установить задержку перед закрытием модального окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт на закрытие модального окна, но как его доработать, чтобы окно закрывалось через 6 секунд??

```
$(function () {
    $(".custom-close").on('click', function() {
        $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать **[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)**

```
$(function () {
    $(".custom-close").on('click', function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');
        }, 6000)            
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!